# Site Feed Web Part times out

Tags: 2013, sitefeed

We have a site feed on the landing page for our SharePoint site, after a minute or two the content disappears until the Heading for the web part is clicked to refresh it.

My understanding is that this web part should just refresh the content not go blank... has anyone else encountered this issue and found a resolution?

Thanks!

Comment: did you see any error in logs? why you think it is time out issue?

Answer (score 0):

Site Feed is part of new social features introduces in SharePoint 2013. Site feed is relying on Distrbuted Cache.

> Distributed Cache service provides caching features in SharePoint
>   Server 2013. The microblog features and feeds rely on the Distributed
>   Cache to store data for very fast retrieval across all entities. The
>   Distributed Cache service is built on Windows Server AppFabric, which
>   implements the AppFabric Caching service. Windows Server AppFabric
>   installs with the prerequisites for SharePoint Server 2013.
>   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219700%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Now make sure couple of things.

- User profile service is up and running.
- MySites are working fine
- Most important, Distributed cache is up and running.
  [Manage the Distributed Cache service in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613.aspx)